# subprocess missing output file

Tags: macos, subprocess, jupyter-notebook, popen

I am completely new to python but I am trying to learn.

I would like to use subprocess command to run a simulation program that can me called in the terminal in a bash environment. The syntax is quite simple: 
    command inputfile.in
where in the the command is a greater simulation script in a tcltk environment.

Ok I have read a lot of the python literature and have decided to use the the Popen functionality of the subprocess command.

So from what I understand I should be able to format the command as follows:

```
   p= subprocess.Popen(['command','inputfile.in'],stdout= subprocess.PIPE])
  print(p.communicate())
```

The output of this command are two files. When I run the command in the terminal I get two files in the same directory as the original input file.

```
File1.fid  File2.spe.
```

When I use Popen there are two things that confuse me.
(1) I do not get any output files written to directory of the input file. (2) The value  p.communicate is present indicating that the simulation was run .

What happen to the output files. Is there a specified way to call a command function that produces files as a result?

I am running this in a Jupyter-notebook cell inside of for loop. This for loop serves to iteratively change the input file thus systematically varying conditions of the simulations. My operating systems is mac osx.

The goal is to simulated or run the command with each iteration of the for loop then store the output file data in a larger dictionary.  Later I would like to compare the output file data to the experimental data iteratively in a optimization process that minimizes the residuals.

I would appreciate any help. Also any direction if popen is not the correct python function to do this.

Comment: Try again with ` p= subprocess.Popen(['command','inputfile.in'],stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`.

Comment: that gives an error from sub process, File "<ipython-input-2-b2ba06bfb0d5>", line 2
    p=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/simpson', fileName],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.  I have `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's learn from something easy like this:

```
# This is equivalent with the command line `dir *.* /s /b` on Windows
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen(['dir', '*.*', '/s', '/b'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(std_out, std_err) = sp.communicate()   # returns (stdout, stderr)

# print out if error occur
print('std_err: ', std_err)   # expect ('std_err: ', '')
# print out saved echoing messages
print('std_out: ', std_out)   # expect ('std_out: ', ... can be a long list ...)
```

Comment: this helped to debug the process. although p communicate showed that the simulation was running there was. final error that had to do with the formatting of a final process in the input file.